# Does direct substitution in multivariable limits save us from checking other possible directions?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

When dealing with a multivariable limit, if we find that direct substitution gives us a valid answer, then can we assume that the limit does exist and not check the other directions where it might not exist?

For example, given the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{2xy}{x^2+2y^2},$$
we find through direct substitution that it approaches $2/3$. Would we care about approaching it from the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, etc.?

Comment: here the function is continuous at $(1,1)$ (because you're taking a quotient of polynomials and the denominator doesn't vanish), which is why direct substitution works and you don't have to check anything else. In general you can't directly substitute.

Answer (score 1):

1）
it is necessary to check.other possible approach, if you plug in (0,0), the value2/3 is just the y value at the point (0,0),it doesn't represent the limit of the f(x,y) when（x，y）approaches（0,0）.

2）
in analysis， the existence of limit  at a point has nothing to do with the existence of the function's value of this point.
take some simple function for example
let
f(x)=1/x (x≠0),
=1     (x=0)
when x approaches 0, f(x) approaches ±∞. but if you plug in x=0, the function's value is 1

3)
for your example,let y=kx, y approaches 0 along the line kx,
so you substitute, and you find out that
f(x,kx)(x⇒0)=k/1+2k², this value varies in terms of different k, so the limit dose not exist